# Regex for hook character on dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame such as :

```
>>> tab2
   group                                names
0      1  ['Gorilla_gorilla,Pan_troglodytes']
1      2               ['Papio_cynocephalus']
2      3                    ['Hylobates_lar']
```

and I would like to remove the [' and '] part and get,

```
>>> tab2
   group                                names
0      1  Gorilla_gorilla,Pan_troglodytes
1      2               Papio_cynocephalus
2      3                    Hylobates_lar
```

I tried:

```
tab2["names"].replace({"['" : "", "']" : ""},regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Are the values in `names` column of type `list` or `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be confusing string representation of the data in your dataframe with strings on which you failed to operate.

The column you are trying to change seems to be of type `list` (represented by `[`) of length 1. The only values of the lists being of the type `str` (that is why those values are between `'` characters).

You may want to extract the only value from each of the lists in the following way:

```
tab2["names"] = tab2["names"].apply(lambda a: a[0])
```

Comment: I get this result :     >>> tab2["names"] = tab2["names"].apply(lambda a: a[0])
>>> tab2
   group names
0      1     [
1      2     [
2      3     [

Answer (score 2):

Is that list type columns ? If so

```
df['name']=df['name'].str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution should do the job:

```
import re

tab2["names"] = tab2["names"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"[\[\]\']",'',x))
```

---

Do mind that this solution would remove all **[ ] ,**, regardless of the position within the string. Edit the regex with ^ and $ for more restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

You are going in the right direction, remember '[' and "'" (single-quotes) have special meaning and should be escaped with a back-slash: "\" Use:

`tab2["names"].replace({"['" : "", "']" : ""},regex=True,inplace=True)`